# How to Rename SWIG Generated Proxy Java classes created from C Structures

Tags: swig

I have a few C structures like below that are generated by SWIG into sample_struct_t.java since the C function declares it as sample_struct_t.  What would I need to add to the SWIG interface file to generate the sample_struct_t structure as Sample.java?

```
typedef struct sample_struct_t_ {
    char                               *sample;
    uint8_t                             example;
    ios_boolean                         remove;
} sample_struct_t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `%rename` with the non-`typedef`'d (i.e. original) name, before this is first seen:

```
%module test

%rename (Sample) sample_struct_t_;

typedef struct sample_struct_t_ {
    char                               *sample;
    uint8_t                             example;
    ios_boolean                         remove;
} sample_struct_t;
```

Comment: I was missing putting in the typedef of the C struct in the SWIG Interface file, thanks!

Comment: do you always have to spell out the whole structure (specify all attributes..etc) in order to do a rename on it?  I have a few typedef struct session session_t; declarations in my header file that don't have a body and I can't find a further declaration in any of that header files includes.  I tried to rename it like above (minus the body) but it wouldn't rename.

Comment: @c12 - There needs to be some definition available I think. That definition can literally be `struct Foo { };` though for SWIG's purposes.

Comment: I tried %rename (ResultRow) result_row_t;
typedef struct result_row_t {} resultrowvar; and the compiler didn't like the empty body. I get a error: invalid application of `sizeof' to incomplete type /path/to/headerfile.h.  Any ideas?