# How to Rename SWIG Generated Proxy Java classes created from C enum types

Tags: swig

I'm trying to use the SWIG rename to change the name for the auto generated proxy Java class, test_cache_t.java to Example.java.  I've tried the below, as it works fine for C structs as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440115/how-to-rename-swig-generated-proxy-java-classes-created-from-c-structures/8444962#comment10444840_8444962) but it's not working for C enums.  Any ideas? I'm getting some warnings that don't quite lead me to the problem...

```
%module Example

%rename (Example) test_cache_t_;
typedef enum test_cache_t_ {
    CACHE_FALSE = 0,
    CACHE_TRUE = 1
} test_cache_t;

%{
  #include "Example.h"
%}
%include "Example.h"
[exec] /test/include/Example.h:84: Warning 302: Identifier 'test_cache_t' redefined (ignored) (Renamed from 'test_cache_t_'),
[exec] test.i:7: Warning 302: previous definition of 'test_cache_t' (Renamed from 'test_cache_t_').
[exec] /test/include/Example.h:82: Warning 302: Identifier 'CACHE_FALSE' redefined (ignored),
[exec] test.i:5: Warning 302: previous definition of 'CACHE_FALSE'.
[exec] /test/include/Example.h:84: Warning 302: Identifier 'CACHE_TRUE' redefined (ignored),
[exec] test.i:7: Warning 302: previous definition of 'CACHE_TRUE'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here I think:

1. Your module has the same name as your (`%rename`d) type, so you have two things wanting to be Example.java.

   Solution: change the name of either the module or the new name from `%rename`
2. It looks like you've provided SWIG two definitions of the same `enum`, once in the interface file and once in the header file.

   Solution: probably remove `typedef enum test_cache_t_` from the interface file, alternatively use `%ignore` before the `%include`, or drop the `%include` altogether.

My final interface file when testing ended up looking like:

```
%module SomeOtherName

%{
  #include "Example.h"
%}

%rename (Example) test_cache_t;

%include "Example.h"
```

Oddly for this to work I had to use the `typedef`'d name in the `%rename`, not the `enum` name. I'm not quite sure why that seems to be the opposite of the case for `struct`/`class`.

Comment: #2 was my issue.  I was using the "Example" name in place of the real names.